# Link share with facebook comments

Tags: facebook, comments, sharing, facebook-comments, facebook-sharer

So, on my blog I post about stuff, and then I share it on Facebook. Currently, I get more feedback on my posts on Facebook than I do on my blog. Is there any way to use Facebooks own comment function on my blog and have the it linked to the shared item on my wall?

I.e. I post "Hello World" on my blog, I share it to my facebook wall, which gets 20 comments. On my blog, I use the Facebook comment widget which will aloow anyone to comment on my "Hello World" post, but it will also show the 20 comments from my facebook wall post, and the other way around - if someone comments on my blog post, it is shown in my facebook wall as well (not as important, however).

Comment: What CMS/blog platform do you use?

Comment: It is a CMS I built myself, actually.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook comments plugin allows users to post comments to their wall as long as they are at the top level.

[image: Post to Facebook]

If "Post to Facebook" is not selected, the post will not appear on the user's wall. If it is selected, any comment in reply shall appear on both the plugin and the user's post on Facebook.

[image: Post on Wall]

[image: Post on Plugin]

Now say you want *every post* to be stored on both, you will need to disable the option to deselect "Post to Facebook", which I think is equivalent to obscuring a plugin. So this isn't a nice option.

*Option 2*

Share a link to your wall, enable public commenting and grab the post ID. Then you can do an HTTP POST to `POST_ID/comments` endpoint with `publish_stream` permissions.

Problem here is that replies will be only under your post, merging any separate threads that can occur on the official Facebook Plugin. Also you need to ask the user for permission to add your app, adding an extra layer of friction.

*Option 3*

Build over the plugin using `FB.Event.subscribe` on a `comment.create` event. The response should give you the comment ID which you can use to grab the name of the user and the message. Then you post that message using your page or profile using the same method from option 2. Doesn't seem authentic as it is not the users posting themselves but it doesn't add any more friction.

See http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9873608/posting-comment-to-facebook-from-javascript to see how Option 3 can work

Comment: Great reply, thanks.


To be clear, do you assert that this scenario is NOT possible with Facebook Comments?


1. I share a link to my blog entry (with Facebook Comments plugin) on my Facebook Page.

2. Comments made on the shared link by my page's fans will show up in the Comments plugin on the blog entry.

3. Comments made by people on the blog entry's Comments plugin will show up on my Facebook Page's shared link?

Comment: @DanielI-S without explicitly asking each user to grant access to their `publish_stream` permissions, no, that scenario is not possible

Answer (score 4):

If you use WordPress then try the WordBooker plugin. 
[WordBooker Home Page](http://www.wordbooker.tty.org.uk)

I think it's the closest to what you're looking for. [Read this post first](http://wordbooker.tty.org.uk/supportforums/topic/problems-with-the-use-of-facebook-comment-box/#post-10976) though regarding how it handles comments.  Best of luck with it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use facebook comments plugin, your all comments are transferable from both sides and stored on facebook.

For Wordpress blog, see following posts for adding facebook comments to your blog.

1. [You tube search results for adding wordpress blog](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Facebook+Comment+Box+to+WordPress+Blog&oq=Facebook+Comment+Box+to+WordPress+Blog&gs_l=youtube-reduced.3...575210.575210.0.575869.1.1.0.0.0.0.379.379.3-1.1.0...0.0...1ac.1.owobmbJX2k4)
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBwbvpqy_Ds
3. http://techmell.com/blogging-tips/how-to-add-facebook-comments-box-to-wordpress/
4. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/

For any blogs,

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrP9gsqsTF0
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7GfE5SrKPM
3. http://www.blogger.webaholic.co.in/2011/09/facebook-comment-box-for-blogger.html
4. http://www.allblogtools.com/tricks-and-hacks/exclusive-integrate-facebook-comments-box-for-blogger-in-very-easy-and-simple-steps-full-guide/

You need to take proper approach according to your blog.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook AWD](http://facebook-awd.ahwebdev.fr/features/comments-box/)  is a social plugin for WordPress, one of it features enables user commenting on your site. Features include moderation tools and distribution. This plugin can automatically add the comments box on your pages, your articles and custom post types.

Hope this plugin solves your problem.